# Make UITextField inside a table view visible scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITableViewController, a bunch of sections and rows, and for each row I added a UITextField as a subview, right aligned in the row itself.

If the users taps on the row, I locally save the indexPath, make the corresponding text field become the first responder and finally, when the keyboard appears, I make the table view scroll so that the row remains visible.

I am facing the problem to obtain the same behaviour when the user taps the text field instead. In this case the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method isn't called, so I do not know how to tell the table view to scroll to make sure that the "selected" row is still visible.

Probably the whole process is not correct. Do you know a way to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure about this, but...

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the `UITextField` to `NO`. This way, the touch goes "through" the control, tapping the `UITableViewCell`. When `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called, set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the `UITextField` to `YES`. When the editing is complete, change it back to `NO`.

Comment: Good, it surely works that way. I only am afraid that the UITextFields can be left with the userInteractionEnabled flag set to YES if I dismiss the keyboard in strange ways (es. touching other controls, or switching tab bar views and so on).

Comment: If you implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidEndEditing:` and set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` there, that won't happen.

Comment: @marzapower: If you need any more help with this, let me know.